# Running Node app in Docker container with aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker

**Background**
I have a node app that essentially needs to use aws-sdk to access S3 bucket and perform other operations. In my local machine I have a .aws config file that sits in ~/.aws/config. I want to run this node app in a docker container (so that I can deploy it to EC2 later).

**The problem**
How do I configure my docker container to use the aws config file so that the node app running in it can use aws-sdk?

**Clarification**
I do not want to use IAM. I specifically want to use aws config file which has the secret access key etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what AWS is doing when they explain how to use their containers on local machines. For example, for [local AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-an-aws-glue-etl-pipeline-locally-without-an-aws-account/) they simply share the `~/.aws/` with the docker container using:

```
-v ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
```

Obviously you would have to adjust the paths above to match your local and docker setup.

The other way is to pass the AWS credentials using docker environment variables.